# SQL XPath compare variable with empty XML node

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery-sql

I have the following code:

```
declare @mydoc xml
declare @myPhone nvarchar(12) = '2223334445'
declare @lastName nvarchar(100) = 'John'
declare @myEmail nvarchar(100) = null
set @mydoc = '<details>
                    <phone />
                    <email />
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </details>'


select @mydoc.exist('/details[fn:lower-case(lastname[1])=fn:lower-case(sql:variable("@lastName"))
                            and (phone[1]=sql:variable("@myPhone") 
                                 or phone[1]=fn:concat(fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,1,3),"-",fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,4,3), "-", fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,7,4))
                                 or (fn:lower-case(email[1])=fn:lower-case(sql:variable("@myEmail")) and not(fn:lower-case(sql:variable("@myEmail"))="null"))
                                 )]')
```

Basically I want to return the details node if it contains the given lastname AND either an email or a phone (provided that they are not empty or null). I would expect the above code to return 0, because even if the lastname = John, the phone is empty and not equal to @myPhone and the email is null. However, it returns 1.

If I change my code like below (removed the email part) it works just fine, returns 0.

```
declare @mydoc xml
declare @myPhone nvarchar(12) = null --'2223334445'
declare @lastName nvarchar(100) = 'John'
declare @myEmail nvarchar(100) = null
set @mydoc = '<lead>
                    <phone />
                    <email />
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </lead>'


select @mydoc.exist('/lead[fn:lower-case(lastname[1])=fn:lower-case(sql:variable("@lastName"))
                            and (phone[1]=sql:variable("@myPhone") 
                                 or phone[1]=fn:concat(fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,1,3),"-",fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,4,3), "-", fn:substring(sql:variable("@myPhone") ,7,4)))]')
```

What am I missing about the email part? In the first example I checked that email is not null, because initially I thought that was the problem, but as seen from the second example, the query works fine in the absence of the null check, for the phone node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @mydoc xml;
declare @myPhone nvarchar(12) = '2223334445';
declare @lastName nvarchar(100) = 'JOHN';
declare @myEmail nvarchar(100)= 'TESTmail@mail.org';

set @mydoc = '<details>
                    <phone>123456</phone>
                    <email>testmail@mail.org</email>
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </details>';
select @mydoc.exist('
/details[lastname[lower-case(.)=lower-case(sql:variable("@lastName"))]][phone[lower-case(.)=lower-case(sql:variable("@myPhone"))] or email[lower-case(.)=lower-case(sql:variable("@myEmail"))]]');  
go


declare @mydoc xml
declare @myPhone nvarchar(12) = '2223334445'
declare @lastName nvarchar(100) = 'John'
declare @myEmail nvarchar(100) = null
set @mydoc = '<details>
                    <phone />
                    <email />
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </details>';


select @mydoc.exist('/details[lastname=sql:variable("@lastName")][phone=sql:variable("@myPhone") or email=sql:variable("@myEmail")]');
---------
set @mydoc = '<details>
                    <phone>2223334445</phone>
                    <email />
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </details>'
select @mydoc.exist('/details[lastname=sql:variable("@lastName")][phone=sql:variable("@myPhone") or email=sql:variable("@myEmail")]');
---------
set @myEmail = 'testmail@mail.org'
set @mydoc = '<details>
                    <phone>123456</phone>
                    <email>testmail@mail.org</email>
                    <lastname>John</lastname>
              </details>';
select @mydoc.exist('/details[lastname=sql:variable("@lastName")][phone=sql:variable("@myPhone") or email=sql:variable("@myEmail")]');
```

Comment: It works this way, but you removed the fn:lower-case() functions which I need because from what I've seen, the equality is case sensitive. And this implies using the [1] predicate next to each node name. If I add that in your first example, it still doesn't work. Could you please explain what you thought was wrong? Unfortunately this approach does not fully address my problem, I need to ignore casing on equality.

Comment: This works if myEmail has value and <email> node has value as well. If you run the first query in your example with the set of data that I provided in my first example, the result is still wrong (1 when it should be 0). From this I understand that the problem is with the fact that no value is provided, but I do not know how to go around that.

Comment: the problem is that the NULL variable(s) become an empty string in xquery:  `declare @t varchar(10)=null;select cast('' as xml).query('concat("the value of @t is:", sql:variable("@t"))')` ... it is easy to filter out "empty" nodes

Comment: Oh my. I get it now. I just changed the ="null" in my initial example with ="" and it worked. Thank you very much. I will also try your example, the code seems a little bit more clean. Do you know if there is another way to check for inequality besides this : not(sql:variable("@myEmail")="null")?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/comparison-expressions-xquery